# Adding a margin

Tags: android, css

I would like to have a margin between the two quotes.Currently the two quotes appear without any paragraph or break one on top of the other. I tried adding the

```
  <TextView
   android:id="quotes_id 212"

   android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    />
```

Between the closing `</quotes>` and opening `<quotes>` in the next quote but I get errors. I'm new as you can probably guess. I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

```
<root>
    <quotes>
        <quotes_id>211</quotes_id>
        <quotes_details><![CDATA[Failure will never overtake me if my     determination to succeed is strong enough.]]></quotes_details>
        <quotes_authorname>Og Mandino</quotes_authorname>
        <quotes_imageurl><!    [CDATA[http://darchwonders.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/og-mandino.jpg]]>    </quotes_imageurl>
    </quotes>

    <quotes>
    <quotes_id>212</quotes_id>
    <quotes_details><![CDATA[A creative man is motivated by the desire to achieve, not by the desire to beat others.]]></quotes_details>
    <quotes_authorname>Ayn Rand</quotes_authorname>
    <quotes_imageurl><![CDATA[http://www.nndb.com/people/097/000030007/ayn-rand-wtl_big.jpg]]></quotes_imageurl>
</quotes>
```

Comment: _"but I get errors"_ -- it would help if you clued us in as to what errors you get.

Comment: Sorry I mean I get errors showing on the xml file as not appropriate code

Answer (score 0):

You may want to style like this

```
quotes{
  margin-right:20px;;
}
```

**here is a snippet**

```css
quotes{
  margin-right:20px;;
}
```

```html
<root>
    <quotes>
        <quotes_id>211</quotes_id>
        <quotes_details><![CDATA[Failure will never overtake me if my     determination to succeed is strong enough.]]></quotes_details>
        <quotes_authorname>Og Mandino</quotes_authorname>
        <quotes_imageurl><!    [CDATA[http://darchwonders.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/og-mandino.jpg]]>    </quotes_imageurl>
    </quotes>

    <quotes>
    <quotes_id>212</quotes_id>
    <quotes_details><![CDATA[A creative man is motivated by the desire to achieve, not by the desire to beat others.]]></quotes_details>
    <quotes_authorname>Ayn Rand</quotes_authorname>
    <quotes_imageurl><![CDATA[http://www.nndb.com/people/097/000030007/ayn-rand-wtl_big.jpg]]></quotes_imageurl>
</quotes>
```

Comment: note ALL quotes in this case will have a margin-right of 20px...if you want to make one quote have a margin simply add an id to that quote and style that quote using css

Comment: Or you can use the rule `quote:first-child { ... }` to restrict the margin to the only first `<quote>` tag.